# How to install nupkg from local file which is generated after done gulp build

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget, cakebuild

I want to install the below nupkg from my local machine throw powershell.

C:\ServerPublishing\build\javascript\reports\release\packages\BoldReport.Server.3.1.92.nupkg

I have tried and get the below result.
[image]

Please give my suggestion for install this nupkg locally.

Comment: @maradev21 "from my local machine"

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to add a custom nuget source, by adding a `NuGet.config` file in the project/solution root; the format of this is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file), but the short version is:

```xml
<config>
    <add key="SomeNameDoesNotMatter" value="D:\SomeFolder" />
</config>
```

Now put your nupkg in `D:\SomeFolder`, and repeat the package install step.

Comment: Hi @Marc Gravell I am currently working in cake build. So, I have cloned my repository to my local folder folder and made npm stall and gulp build.  Now need to install the .nupkg file from the gulp generated package folder. I could not install that nupkg file. I have tried 'Install-Package nuget.nupkg ' This type of command. But, I could not get the proper result from this.